# Why am I unable to enter % sign after my custom validation

Tags: javascript, validation, keycode

I have a requirement wherein I can enter number not more than 100 (100 allowed). Additionally these number can have `+`, `-` sign at start and `%` at the end.

I have come up with the following function to validate. However, even after struggling a lot, I am unable to fix why I am not able to enter a `%` sign when I have already enter 2 digits.

Ex: after typing 10, I cant type `%` (Shift + 5)
My Function:

```
$scope.checkInputValidation = function(event, value) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    var currentcharacter = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (key === 91 || key === 187 || key === 189 || (15 < key && key < 19) || (35 <= key && key <= 40)) {
        return;
    }
    if (isNaN(currentcharacter) && ((currentcharacter !== "%") || (currentcharacter !== "+") || (currentcharacter !== "-") || (currentcharacter !== ""))) {
        if ((key !== 46) && (key !== 8)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
    var formattedValue;
    if (value.indexOf('%') !== -1) {
        formattedValue = value.replace('%', "");
    } else {
        formattedValue = value;
    }
    if (!isNaN(currentcharacter)) {
        if (parseInt(formattedValue + currentcharacter) > 100 || parseInt(formattedValue + currentcharacter) < -100) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know the cause and how should I be able to enter `%`.

Comment: check String value is equal to 100 or not

Comment: What does string value 100 refers to ?

Comment: `currentcharacter` is never going to contain `%`. You have to check the keyCode for 5 (53) in combination with the `event.shiftKey` property. `if(key === 53 && event.shiftKey) { .. % pressed .. }`

Comment: thanks A1rPun...your suggestion worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentcharacter` is never going to contain the `%` character. You have to check the keyCode for `5` (53) in combination with the `event.shiftKey` property.

```
if(key === 53 && event.shiftKey) {
    .. % pressed ..
}
```